# How to create a Numeric format from a character strings in SAS?

Tags: format, sas

I am working in some code development related to clinical study. I have multiple visits, like baseline, week 01, and so on. To avoid the use of multiple IF-ELSE statements for assigning numeric values to these visits, I just creating formats using format procedure.

```
proc format;
 value _vis $ 'baseline'='1'
            'week01'='2'
            'week02'='3' ;
run;
```

But I am looking for is like baseline having a value 1(numeric) not character. Is there any way out for this problem. Please help.

Comment: It would really help if you could advise how you are using the formatted values

Comment: FORMAT shows SAS how to display in character a value (either numeric or character).  INFORMAT shows SAS how to convert to numeric a value (either character or numeric).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change your format to an informat...

```
proc format;
  invalue vis /* INvalue = informat */
    'baseline' = 1
    'week01'   = 2
    'week02'   = 3 
  ;
run;

data data1 ;
  d = 'baseline' ;
  n = input(d,VIS.) ;
run ;
proc print ; run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
proc format;
 value $_vis 
'baseline'='1'
'week01'='2'
'week02'='3';
run;

data test;
length vis $8.;
vis = 'baseline';
output;
vis = 'week01';
output;
vis = 'week02';
output;
run;

data test2;
set test;
vis2=vis;
format vis2 _vis.;
vis3=input(put(vis2, _vis.),8.);
run;
```

test2:

```
vis     vis2    vis3
baseline    1   1
week01      2   2
week02      3   3
```

where vis & vis2 are character variables and vis3 is a numeric variable.

Is this what you are looking for?